# Windows 8 asks DotNet 3.5 to install DotNet 3.5

Tags: windows-8, .net-framework

While trying to install some tools in Windows 8, it showed me a nice message saying it requires DotNet framework. Well, it's fine. But the bad part is I have offline installers for v2.0 and v3.5. While I'm trying to install those installers it shows me the same message as it shows above.

I can't consider the web installer, because I don't want to download around 100MB. The file I have works fine for other versions like Windows 7 or XP.

Any fixes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also install it offline:

1. Mount your Windows 8 installer (DVD/USB/ISO).
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>.
3. Run the following command: (Change X: to the letter of the Windows 8 installer)

   ```
   dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:X:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
   ```

   [image]

Answer (score 15):

.Net 3.5 is a feature in Windows 8, that is "off" by default. Turning the feature "on" will have the same effect as installing it.

To turn the feature on, type "Windows Features" on the start screen and under settings you'll see "Turn Windows features on or off."

In there put a check mark next to .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)

[image: Windows Features]

It could take a few minutes and request a restart, but once it is done you will have .NET 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5.

Comment: It requires Internet connection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh506443(v=VS.110).aspx That's what I don't want.

Comment: Then use the offline method posted by "User" below.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to use the installer, simply go to "Turn Windows Features on or off", and enable .Net 3.5 in there.